# python subprocess popen set home directory as cwd

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I have a small problem. I'm on a ubuntu 16.04 machine and in a python script I want to start a subprocess which should start in the home directory of the user. I tried it with:

```
subprocess.Popen('echo "Test"', cwd="~", shell=True,universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/bin/bash")
```

but when I do this I get the following error:

```
 proc = subprocess.Popen('echo "test"', cwd="~", shell=True,universal_newlines=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/bin/bash")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~'
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong since when you enter ~ in a cd command it cds you to the home directory. I hope someone has a solution 
why it is not working this way and what would be the right way to start it in the home directory.

Comment: Is this python 3.6 or later?

Comment: The version I'm using is 3.5 I hope that helps sorry for not including this

Comment: No need to apologise -- I've posted a solution below

Comment: `~` is interpreted by shell but not as passed in `cwd=` parameter. Because `cwd=` parameter is processed before launching the shell. You may see it in cpython code specifically `Modules/_posixsubprocess.c:child_exec` function if needed.

Comment: This sounds vaguely like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) anyway. Well-written software generally doesn't care which directory it's being run in, and overriding the user's current working directory is often an unwelcome surprise.

Comment: it is not depending  that it is run in there, but the programm wants to search some files which should be located starting from the home directory of the user  so it is needed in this case but yes in general it is not a 100% good idea I agree .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I've simplified your code for clarity.*

---

With Python 3.6 or higher you can do the following:

```
import subprocess, pathlib
subprocess.Popen(['echo',  'test'], cwd=pathlib.Path.home())
```

With Python 3.5 you need to wrap `Path.home()` into `str()`:

```
import subprocess, pathlib
subprocess.Popen(['echo',  'test'], cwd=str(pathlib.Path.home()))
```

With any Python version below 3.5 you can use:

```
import os, subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['echo',  'test'], cwd=os.path.expanduser('~'))
```

Comment: Thank you verry much, that did the trick  , didn't know that this even exists :)